# Can't print the sizeof a signed int type

Tags: c++, c

Why when I try to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("Size of int: %d bytes\n",sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

I got this:

```
warning: format "%d" expects argmuments of int type, but the second argument is of type "long unsigned int..."
```

(?)

If it counts, my OS is Ubuntu of 64bits of version 12.4.
The compiler is: GNU GCC Compiler and the IDE is Code::Blocks.

For curiosity, I run the same code in another machine which run a poor Win7 and the structure is 64bits too, the result I got was the size of that int and not a warning like above.

Comment: I don't think Microsoft tries to parse the format of a `printf` to see if the arguments are OK or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
printf("Size of int: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(int));
```

`sizeof` operator yields a value of type `size_t` and `%zu` is the correct conversion specification to print a value of type `size_t`.

If you have a compiler that doesn't support c99 or c11, you can do:

```
printf("Size of int: %lu bytes\n", (unsigned long) sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
printf("Size of int: %lu bytes\n", sizeof(int));
```

Comment: This will not be correct (and in fact, unsafe) on LLP64 systems like Windows, where long is still 32-bits. You have to cast the result of sizeof(int) to unsigned long if this needs to work safely.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Size of int: %zd bytes\n",sizeof(int))
```

Comment: "zd" is not correct, because it implies a signed type.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` returns a `size_t` type, which in some cases will be larger than an `int`. This will mess up the stack as the wrong size parameter is pulled off by `printf`. You will almost certainly see incorrect results for any parameters printed after the `sizeof`.

Comment: So what's the/a solution?

Comment: @user2864740, use the correct format code which is found in other answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the value

```
printf("Size of int: %d bytes\n", (int)sizeof (int));
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` yields `size_t`.  Using the format specifier "%zu" should provide the proper formatting:

```
printf("Size of int: "%zu bytes\n", sizeof(int));
```

This format specifier is ***C99 compliant***.
If you do not have C99 compliant compiler, you can cast sizeof to unsigned int and use "%lu"

```
printf("Size of int: "%lu bytes\n", (unsigned int)sizeof(int));
```

***If however***, you are using ***[visual studios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tcxf1dw6.aspx)***, according to Microsoft, the correct format specifier for size_t is `%Iu`

```
printf("Size of int: "%Iu bytes\n", sizeof(int));
```

Comment: `sizeof` is not a macro but an operator. As it is not a function, it does not *return*. The type of the value it yields is always `size_t` and never `ssize_t`.

Comment: @ouah -  Made edits to remove those issues.  However, I would like to hear what you say to distinguish between the terms `returns` and `yields`.  Thanks.

Comment: @rykker I didn't downvote but this is still wrong. `sizeof` is not a macro. Moreover not casting `sizeof` to `unsigned long` may invoke undefined behavior as `size_t` can be an alias to `unsigned long long` on some implementations.